# Set system time using SNMP?

Tags: windows, snmp, time

Is it possible to set system time on Windows Server using SNMP?

So you push out the time instead of using NTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, that on Windows this is impossible.

```
$ snmpset -c qqq 192.168.1.92 HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = 2013-5-5,18:9:46.1
Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0
```